# How can I build vim with a gui without gtk?

Tags: python, gui, vim, pygtk, gvim

I've recently started playing around with pygobject. 
However, gvim or vim's python-complete feature crashes, because, as I understand, you cannot mix GTK2 and GTK3 libraries in the same process.

Therefore, I'd like to know how to install Vim with a non-GTK toolkit.
(sudo apt-get build-dep vim will try to install gtk2 libs.)

Please note that I'm very happy with Vim, and I don't want to switch editors.

I've found instructions to build vim with qt, however python-complete is not working properly.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the instructions you found to build vim with qt, and any details you have about how this breaks python-complete? (You can **edit your question** to include this information.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you built `vim` against Qt rather than GTK+ and `python-complete` still isn't working, that suggests the problem isn't actually a consequence of trying to link to both GTK+2 and GTK+3.

However, since you haven't yet provided any details about how you built with Qt (Qt isn't officially supported, so you must have used a third party derivative of `vim`), and you haven't provided any detailed information about what error messages or malfunctions you're having with `python-complete`, it's not really possible to tell you how to fix the problem and get `vim` working with Qt.

**Fortunately, `vim` officially supports some GUI's other than GTK+ and Qt, and one such build is officially packaged for Ubuntu.**

Just install the [Athena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Athena) version of `vim`, which is [provided](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/vim-athena) by the [vim-athena [image: Install vim-athena]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vim-athena) package.

You can install by clicking the package link above, or searching for it in the Software Center or Synaptic Package Manager, or running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vim-athena
```

`vim-athena` doesn't depend on or use any version of GTK+. If you use `sudo apt-get build-dep vim-athena`, it probably will install GTK+ and GNOME related libraries, *because the `vim-athena` binary package is built from the [same source package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim) as `vim` and other `vim`-providing packages*. In any case, you shouldn't need to build from source, as the binaries provided by `vim-athena` are already built against Athena and not against GTK+ or other graphical toolkits.

Comment: Oh, Thanks. Working like a charm.(even pythoncomplete!)