# How to build vim with gui option from sources?

Tags: compiling, gui, vim

I'm having a hard time building a `VIM` 7.4(obtained from vim's ftp site) with `gui` option. It builds ok without the `gui`
option. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
cd ~/Downloads/vim74/src
./configure --enable-gui
```

The above line does not seem to work because I get this output from the command:

```
./configure --enable-gui | grep gui
checking --enable-gui argument... no GUI support
```

I uncommented line 352 of the makefile to enable  the gui(I think):

```
CONF_OPT_GUI = --enable-gui=gtk2
```

But when I run `vim -g`(after rebuilding) I get:

```
E25: GUI cannot be used: Not enabled at compile time
```

There's a suggestion in the makefile to check the generated `auto/config.h` and
`auto/config.mk` files  but the files are empty(less than 10 lines).
**How do you fix this?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I build vim with a gui without gtk?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/165516/how-can-i-build-vim-with-a-gui-without-gtk)

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I'm not looking for the appropriate `apt` command, it would probably work(haven't tried it). I want a solution for when compiling from its sources.

Comment: Ok, I will retract the close vote, but I will let the comment for future users.

Comment: Did you do a `make install` or just a `make`? if the latter, then in order to run the newly-built binary you must specify the path explicitly i.e. if you are in the `vim74` directory where you issued the `make` command, do `./src/vim -g` . It should not be necessary to specify any additional options to `configure`, I just tested it and the default configuration produced a GUI-enabled executable.

Comment: @steeldriver, I've tried both with no luck. Mine does not even generate the `./src/vim -g` folder, how'd you do that? Please outline the steps you are using.

Comment: I just downloaded the vim-7.4.tar.bz2 file, untarred it into my current directory `tar xvf ../Downloads/vim-7.4.tar.bz2 -C . `, then `cd vim74`, `./configure`, `make`. You may find it helpful to use `./configure --help` to see the available configuration options. In particular, the `--enable-gui` option needs an `=OPT` argument (and it appears to default to `--enable-gui=auto`)

Comment: I've tried with `--enable-gui=gtk2` and `--enable-gui=gnome2` but it still outputs `no GUI support`. What do you have for the line that starts with `checking --enable-gui argument`?

Comment: I've decided to give up on this endeavor. I've installed it using `apt`. I'm guessing the `no GUI support` is because I'm missing some libraries or something.

Answer (score 8):

To build Vim you will need first to install all the dependencies. This could be done using

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep vim-gtk # or vim-gnome, if you prefer.
```

This will download and install a lot of packages that should only be needed to compile Vim. If you don't want to keep them, before running that command add this to `/etc/apt/apt.conf`

```
APT {
  Get {
     Build-Dep-Automatic "true";
  };
};
```

This will make all the packages installed with `build-dep` be "marked to be autoremoved". So after you finished compiling Vim you can uninstall them using `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

After this, just proceed with the usual steps:

```
$ ./configure --with-gui=gtk2 # or gnome
$ make -j 4
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: For me on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS `sudo apt-get build-dep vim-gtk` showed error until I added "Source code"  checkbox in Software&Updates on "Ubuntu Software" tab. Then I made `sudo apt-get update` and command worked.

Answer (score 3):

If you call `./configure --enable-gui=auto`, the build process will automatically build against whichever GUI libraries are available. A cursory glance suggests that `gtk2` will be prioritised over `gnome2`.

Answer (score 1):

Just run into the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04. Turns out, it happens because packages with headers/libs for GTK2/Gnome aren't installed. After `sudo apt-get install gnome-devel` as [@RAOF](https://askubuntu.com/users/188/raof) advised in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/11260/80879), `vim --version` says it has GUI GTK2 support and `gvim`, `gvimdiff`, `gview` symlinks are created during install.